# Pyplot .plot function generates immediate graph. plt.plot() seems to do nothing

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder

For some reason plots are generated when i run a single line (F9 in Spyder). So in the sequence hereunder first a line plot is generated. The second line generates an empty plot,but with the y-label,and the plt.show() does nothing.
Yesterday i tried making a very simple animation. used export to file. I since then made a total new installation.  Reinstalled Anaconda
I am using Anaconda, Python 3.9.7  matplotlib 3.4.3, Ipython 7.29.0,spyder 3.9.7

What am I missing?

```
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])  #this line makes a simple line plot
plt.ylabel('some numbers') #executing thins line makes a new empty plot with the label
plt.show()  #nothing happens
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLEPg.png)

Comment: IPython consolesettings for graphics backend is "Inline".  The matplotlib backend used is matplotlib.get_backend() => module://matplotlib_inline.backend_inline'

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) What you described is the right behavior for the Inline backend, which (as you discovered) is the one you're using.

To change it and create a plot by evaluating different commands one at a time, you need an interactive backend. To set one, please go to the menu

`Tools > Preferences > IPython console > Graphics`

and select `Automatic` in the `Backend` section. After that, you'll be shown a dialog asking you to restart your kernels, to which you need to agree (if that's not the case, just close Spyder and restart it again).

Answer (score 0):

well , i don't know why exactly but it solves itself if you label the x axis

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])  #this line makes a simple line plot
plt.xlabel('x - axis')
plt.ylabel('some numbers') #executing thins line makes a new empty plot with the label
plt.show()  #nothing happens
```

[image: The Graph]

Comment: I am sorry Daniel, this doesn't work. When I execute the line ,in the plots pane in Spyder, an empty graph is shown with the x-axis label. There is somewhere a setting wrong.

Comment: Then maybe just add an X axis as usual? `plt.plot(X,Y)`